# code that doesn't work...Kill-process , search-for-file , streamwrite on file searched file

Tags: vb.net, find, streamwriter, kill-process, getfiles

can you help me with that code ?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim x As String = "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\minecraft srv\"

    For Each app As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If app.ProcessName = "notepad" Then
            app.Kill()
        End If
    Next

    Dim result As String
    Dim servprop() As String
    servprop = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(x, "server.*")

    For Each file In servprop
        result = Path.GetFileName(file)
    Next

    Dim z As String = "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\minecraft srv\" & result.ToString
    Dim t As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(z)
    t.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text.ToString)
    t.Close()
End Sub
```

so... I got a button (button1) that finds if notepad is opened and kills it.
Then it searches for  "server.Properties" in  "x" location
if server.properties  is found , then "result" will get his name (server)
"z" is the file location where streamwriter must write the text from textbox1 .

And it doesn't work... streamwirter is not writing on server.properties  ... why ?
mention : I'm just a kid :D and i'm trying to learn by myself  visual basic .

Comment: Too many `End If` and `Next`. Missing pieces of code? And did you get any error message?

Comment: just 1 warning ...:
Variable 'result' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: and I m sure that nothing is missing . Just my bad understanding of commands

Comment: sorry .. you were right... i had too many end if and next...
now it should look right

Comment: If the directory contains more than one file with name that starts with "Server.?????" your loop ends setting the variable result to a file name that could not be the one you hope to write. Check if your directory contains just the "server.properties" file that you are searching for.

Comment: yea.. .there is only one server with extension .properties in this folder

Comment: i get no errors.. but the text is not even touched... is just empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one file called "server.properties" then you could remove all the code that search for this file and write it directly.

```
Dim z As String
z = System.IO.Path.Combine(x, "server.properties")

Using t = New StreamWriter(z)
    t.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text.ToString)
    t.Flush()
End Using
```

Regarding the error, encapsulating the writing code with a proper using statement ensures a complete clean-up. Also adding a call to [Flush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) is probably not necessary, but doesn't hurt.

Comment: Added link to Flush() on MSDN

Comment: Works verry fine .. Thanks again !